# Elderly couple manipulate people in order to steal their bodies

Tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show, drama

I have once seen a movie (or a TV episode, but probably not) with the following plot:

In the beginning, a reporter is making a story on immortality and does interview with a an elderly couple who claim that they can live forever by moving their souls into new bodies. Later, several tragedies happen to him and his family that derail his life and put him into depression. In the end, he finds out that the couple he interviewed are actually capable of stealing bodies as long as soul of the victim is broken and not ready to fight back. So all things that happened to him were part of their plan to use him as a new body for the husband's soul. There is no happy end.

It is all I remember as I watched it 10 or more years ago. I tried several queries on IMDB and Google, but no luck. I am not sure about country where it was made — most probably it is USA, but potentially might be UK/Europe.

Can anyone identify the movie in question?

Comment: I am fairly sure that this is an episode from one of those series like "The Twilight Zone", "Amazing Stories", or "Night Gallery"

Comment: A helpful tool for this kind of thing is the keyword search on http://imdb.com. Try a few words, (e.g., steal soul), to see titles that users have tagged as such, both TV and movies. It also returns similar keywords to try as well.

Comment: Unless I'm also thinking of the Skeleton Key (have seen it many years ago), I'm pretty sure I know it from some movie, not a tv show.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the film you were looking for is [Eternal Evil](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088830/) (AKA The Blue Man) from 1985, starring Winston Rekert and Karen Black. From [an online synopsis](http://horrornews.net/68588/film-review-eternal-evil-1985/):

> The plot focuses on Paul (Winston Rekert), a filmmaker whose last documentary explored a couple’s use of astral projection and their continual survival by possessing the bodies of those whose spirits have been expelled.

And the ending, from [another online synopsis](http://www.weirdwildrealm.com/f-eternalevil.html):

> Paul has been selected for Janus's new body, as the Amelia body is tubercular & worn out. Before a resident soul can be cast out, however, that person must become isolated & in despair.

If you're after some visual confirmation, search for "Eternal Evil" on Youtube. The entire film is there (and the sinister couple in question is indeed old).

Answer (score 2):

The description reminded me of [*The Skeleton Key*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0397101/) with a couple trying to steal a body, but not everything fits so probably not what your looking for

Comment: The question also reminded me of *The Skeleton Key*, but the details don't really match.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a bit like [Being John Malkovich](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120601/) where a large number of people would live on inside a person's head when they die.

Although it's not 100% accurate to what you are suggesting, it is the first thing that popped into my head.

Comment: In this movie people can look through Malkovich's eyes for a while when they enter a certain tunnel/crawlspace, so that's not exactly the same... They don't die.

Comment: @peopje The premise of the film is not about looking through his eyes for a while. If you watch it to the end.

Comment: Oh it has been too long ago for me since I saw the film then :p